# Can a user reside in one group, but write from another?

Tags: permissions, rhel, users, group

We have group Apache and, let's say, "District" group.

All our team members are part of "District" group.

Apache user is part of "Apache" group, and does a lot of work on our server, creating and modifying files. But "Apache" group has fairly strict permissions, so there is no way we "District" group members can write to these files.

How can we help "District" members have write permissions to these files? One way to solve it is to "chmod 777" everything in the Apache group...but...eh. We don't want the *anyone* to be able to edit these files...just people from "District" group.

Question: **Is it possible to make "Apache" user remain in "Apache" group, but write as part of "District" group?** (and, therefore, have all Apache-authored files become accessible to "District" members)

Comment: Use ACL https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-manage-acls-on-linux

Comment: As Christopher says, ACLs are probably what you are looking for. You could set a default ACL on the webroot with write permission for the District group, without changing the octal permissions and the user/group Apache is in

Comment: Thanks, I added a tag for OS (RHEL). I'm honestly a pretty new Linux user, I hadn't heard of ACLs before, I'll check them out!

Comment: Simpler than ACLs is the `setgid` bit on a directory - it forces all new files/subdirs  created to be owned by the group that you did the `setgid` with on the upper level directory.